# Parsing csv file and splitting into sub files

Tags: python, csv, lambda

I am trying to create a generic filter to split file on the condition from the Yaml file.

My code is running Pandas but as the environment is not having Pandas module I am trying to achieve it through CSV library.

When I am hard coding the value at q its working but when I am trying to pass it from the config file its not working. Also I want pass multiple checks on the same column like('','Balance). So `Asset` goest to one file and `('','Balance)` in another.

```
import sys
import yaml
import csv


def dynamicQuery(config_file, data_file, outputPath):
    """Loading Configuration file into dataframe"""
    try:
        with open(config_file) as file:
            doc = yaml.full_load(file)

    except Exception as err:
        print("Error Configuration data file: ", err)

    try:

    for k, v in doc.items():
        if k != 'column':
            filename = k
            k = doc[k]
            q = ' , '.join(f'{v} ' for q, v in k.items())

            q = '"' + str(strip(q)) + '"'
            print(q) #-- "Asset"
            df = csv.reader(open(data_file), delimiter=',')
            df = filter(lambda x: (x[2] == q), df) # Not working here
            #df = filter(lambda x: x[2] == "Asset", df) --> this is working



            csv.writer(open(filename + ".txt", 'w', newline=' '), delimiter=',').writerows(df)
            print("File is created for " + filename)

    except Exception as err:
        print("Error executing queries and saving output data file: ", err)


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        """File will be passed as parameter """
        config_file = sys.argv[1]
        data_file = sys.argv[2]

        dynamicQuery(config_file, data_file)
    else:
        usage()


def usage():
    print("Usage: python splitGenric.py config_file data_file ")


main()
```

Sample file

```
1233,ACV,Asset,sample
1235,ACV,Asset,sample
1232,ACV,Asset,sample
1234,ACV,Asset,sample
1237,ACV,,sample
1238,ACV,,sample
1234,ACV,Balance,sample
1254,ACV,Balance,sample
1244,ACV,Balance,sample
1264,ACV,Balance,sample
```

Config.yaml

```
Asset :
  filter1: '"Asset"'


Balance:
    filter1: '"Balance"'
    filter2: '""'
```

Comment: What do you get in `q` and why do you expect it to be equal to anything from the CSV file? None of your data seems to match (in particular with the forced literal double quotes).

Comment: Fro the config file I am geting q= "Asset", which I want to match from the file. If i hard code " Asset" in the Lambda function it works for only one condition

Comment: You are confusing the syntactic quotes in `q="Asset"` with the literal quotes in, effectively, `q='"Asset"'`. But it's also not clear what the `join` with `' & '` is supposed to create. Can you still edit to clarify how you intended for this logic to work?

Comment: My bad I changed it `,` as I used `' &'` for my pandas code. I used it if I have multiple filter condition in the config file for the same columns I am joining them together with a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML configuration file format is not particularly convenient for this, and `yaml` is not a standard Python module.  I would probably go for something like regular expressions instead of a YAML file. But just to sort out the immediate problems, the problem here is that you are mixing up Python syntax and literal quoting characters.  You are assembling a string containing literal double quotes around `Asset` for example, where your CSV file does not contain double quotes around this value; and so you are effectively comparing `if 'Asset' == '"Asset"'` which of course is `False`.

The following might not do exactly what you want, but should at least demonstrate a rough first cut of what I *think* you are trying to do here.

```py
with open(config_file) as file:
    config = yaml.full_load(file)

filters = dict()
for k, v in config.items():
    handle = open(k + '.txt', 'w', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(handle, delimiter=',')
    filt = {'handle': handle, 'writer': writer, 'conditions': []}
    for _, expr in v.items():
        filt['conditions'].append(expr.strip('"'))
    filters[k] = filt

with open(data_file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        for handle, conf in filters.items():
            for i in range(len(conf['conditions'])):
                if row[2] == conf['conditions'][i]:
                    conf['writer'].writerow(row)
                    break

for handle, conf in filters.items():
    conf['handle'].close()
```

I'm guessing you used `pyyaml` which seems to be the dominant YAML module for Python.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the config.yaml, but I've got this error

```
File "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 439, in parse_block_mapping_key
"expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
in "config.yml", line 5, column 5
expected <block end>, but found ','
in "config.yml", line 5, column 17
```

But I will pretend it worked and the content was loaded in a dictionary, as it appears to be the intention. 
The dictionary is as:

```
doc = {'Asset':'Asset','Balance':[' ','Balance']}

#load directly to dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt',header=None)  

handler = ''
for k,v in doc.items():

    kList = {k:[]} #making empty lists with k values

    if isinstance(v,str): #Asset is string
        fil = v
    else:
        for i in range(len(v)): #Balance is list of values
            if v[i]:
                fil = v[i]
            else:
                handler = k #replace the null                           

    for types in df.values:

        if fil in types:
            kList[k].append(types) #append types to corresponding list

    csv.writer(open(k+".txt", 'a', newline='\n'), delimiter=',').writerows(kList[k])


if handler: #there is null values
    nulls = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)].values.tolist()
    csv.writer(open(handler+".txt", 'a', newline='\n'), delimiter=',').writerows(nulls)
```

The result are two files, with the following contents:

Asset.txt:

```
1233,ACV,Asset,sample
1235,ACV,Asset,sample
1232,ACV,Asset,sample
1234,ACV,Asset,sample
```

Balance.txt:

```
1234,ACV,Balance,sample
1254,ACV,Balance,sample
1244,ACV,Balance,sample
1264,ACV,Balance,sample
1237,ACV,nan,sample
1238,ACV,nan,sample
```

Comment: I managed to read the YAML file just fine with PyYAML; what did you use? The OP seems to be saying they can't use Pandas.

Comment: I saved the yml extesion using Notepad++ and tried to open in IDLE Python.

Comment: Sure, but `import yaml` probably does something different for you than it does for the OP, and we don't know what that is (for either of you actually).